# Where is the frame property in debug view of a UIView?

Tags: ios, debugging, uiview

I see other properties of an object (subview array, gesture recognizers, tag, etc.) in the debug area when I add a breakpoint, but can't find the "frame".  New to using breakpoints and debug features, can't figure this out.  Just want to be able to examine the frame of a UIView at a breakpoint.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debugger's variables pane doesn't show everything, unfortunately.  The easiest way to print out the frame is to NSLog the view itself.  UIView's description method prints the frame values as part of the NSLog message.

If you don't want to put an NSLog in, when you hit the breakpoint you can also do po nameOfView in the gdb console.  That's the same as NSLogging it or calling -description.

Comment: awesome, didn't know you could do that with the debugger!